# taking input in c++ after getline

Tags: c++, cin, getline

I'm facing some issues in taking input in C++ after using `getline`. Following is the piece of code:

```
    cin>>n;

    vector<string>v(n);
    string s, type;
    bool reversed;

    getline(cin, s);

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
        getline(cin, s);
        v[i]=s;
    }

    cin>>key;
    cin>>reversed;
    cin>>type;
```

for the following input --

```
3
92 022
82 12
77 13
2 true digital
```

What I need is the following lines to be taken as string with spaces--

```
92 022
82 12
77 13
```

which I'm able to, but the value of reversed is always 0 and type is always blank. Please help what I'm doing wrong in taking input?

I also had to use `getline` once before for loop to take the input for "n" string correctly. How to avoid that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you set the `boolalpha` flag, `cin >> bool` expects `0` or `1`.

To use literals `"true"` / `"false"`, set [`boolapha`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/boolalpha) like this:

```
  cin >> boolalpha >> reversed;
```